# Can i call a server side script from a hyper link in system generated email?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am developing an application that creates an event in an other employee's google calendar when the Manager approves a vacation request. 
I am able to create events in the calendar I own, but not in the Calendar owned by a colleague. Is there a way to create a special account that can update all calendars in an organization?
If I am not able to make it part of the workflow, I would like to have a hyper link in the email i send to the colleague saying the vacation has been approved and click here to add it to your calendar. I am able to achieve this by creating a page for create event in calendar, is there a way by which i can call the serve side function directly from the hyper link?

Thanks,

Comment: Unfortunately the link is on the client's end and cannot call server side functions. However you could add a page on the server that would pick up the necessary info from the url and then THAT page can do the server side processing. This page need not have any UI and can be pure backend process. And finally you can redirect to display a message of success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation https://web.archive.org/web/20120313011336/http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html
It will help you create link, that will fill Google calendar create event screen.

So user will click link and will see Google calendar create event screen with filled data, he will need just click "save" button

By this link http://useroffline.blogspot.com/2009/06/making-google-calendar-link.html you will find short version of documentation and link sample.